# how to programmatically trigger credit card payment on order in magento2?

Tags: magento2, payment, quote

I need to build an api method which should receive customer's payment information (credit card info) along with product details and place an order with it further processing.

Right now I faced that `braintree` payment facade requires credit card tokenization which is made via javascript during checkout process, as well as authorize.net method is connecting to `transact.dll` endpoint.

Is this actually possible, to trigger order processing only in backend ?

Can I refer somewhere in existing magento2 code to see how it is made, maybe in some adminhtml area ?

The code i use to create an order:

```
    // prepare adresses, products in quote, shipping method - skipped
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('authorizenet_directpost');
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
    // Set Sales Order Payment

    $quote->getPayment()->importData(
        [
            'method'      => 'authorizenet_directpost',
            'card_type'   => $payment->cardType,
            'cvv'         => $payment->cvv,
            'expire_year' => $payment->expireYear
        ]
    );

    $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($contact->email);
   // prepare customer
    $quote->setCustomer($customer);

    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find the customer saved cards list (vault), then you can use one of the cards in the order placement as you described:

```
use Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

... 

// Get the customer id (currently logged in user)
$customerId = $this->session->getCustomer()->getId();

// Card list
$cardList = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getListByCustomerId($customerId);
```

You can use the following methods to get the details of a card. Example on the first card object of the list above:

```
$cardList[0]->getEntityId();
$cardList[0]->getCustomerId();
$cardList[0]->getPublicHash();
$cardList[0]->getPaymentMethodCode();
$cardList[0]->getType();
$cardList[0]->getCreatedAt();
$cardList[0]->getExpiresAt();
$cardList[0]->getGatewayToken();
$cardList[0]->getDetails();
$cardList[0]->getisActive();
$cardList[0]->getIsVisible();
```

Note:
The getListByCustomerId($customerId) function will give you all stored cards for a single customer, whether the cards are active or not. If you only want the list of active cards, use getVisibleAvailableTokens($customerId) instead.